# Redirect to passing some value to the redirected-to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass some value from one component to another once the user clicks a button.

First Component (`Survey`) with a value `survey` --> User clicks a button --> Second component (`Details`) renders the `survey`

To achieve so I am using `Redirect` from the `react-router-dom`.

```
function Survey({survey}) {
....
// There is a button that triggers the below if clause. The redirect works but it seems the state is not sent.
    if (surveyPage === true) {
        return <Redirect to={{
            pathname: '/detail',
            state: { location: survey }
        }}

    }

    return("something")

}
```

Second component

```
function Details(){
    console.log( this.props.location.state.location) // Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
    return "test"
}
```

> > Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

I tried also:

```
function Details({survey){
    console.log(survey) // Undefined
    return "test"
}
```

and

```
function Details({ location: survey }){
    console.log(survey) // Undefined
    return "test"
}
```

I am really not understanding what I am doing wrong. I am following the documentations:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/primary-components

Comment: This is not about `react-route-dom`, it's about how to pass props property to functional component. Since the error is `props undefined`

Comment: I tried also without `this`, but still similar error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not accessable in `functional` components. You need to do it like this:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function Details(props){
    const history = useHistory();
    console.log(history.location.state.location);

    return <p>Test</p>
}

export default Details;
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

To connect your component to the routes information, you should use the **withRouter** HOC or **useHistory** hook.

withRouter example:

```js
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

function Details(props){
    console.log(props.history.location.state.location);

    return <p>Test</p>
}

export default withRouter(Details);
```